# Golang HTTP Timeout test, not timing out as expected

Tags: http, go, timeout

I built a small testcase, that checks that code on my end timesout after a set amount of time has passed. But this isnt working as expected

I am hitting an server sided endpoint which works fine, but what happens if it is slower than usual, I will need code on my end to timeout, this has been implemented but I need to test that I implemented it correctly.

This is what I have so far

```
func TestTimeout(t *testing.T) {
ts := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 15)
}))
defer ts.Close()
client := &http.Client{
    Timeout: time.Second * 10,
}
myRequest,err := createMyRequest(Somedata,SomeMoreData)
res, err := client.Do(myRequest)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
res.Body.Close()}
```

However my code successfully runs without giving a timeout error (as in I am not waiting for 10 seconds, where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are not reading the body. Use io.ReadAll to read the body, and you should receive the timeout while waiting for the read to complete.

Comment: I do not understand, how would I do this?

Comment: After `client.Do`, call `_,err:=ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)`

Comment: @CeriseLimón I need to send a Post request not a GET Request, hence why I use do()

Comment: ts.URL is  a string, which contains the URL of the endpoint I am attempting to hit is that right?, but this is a POST request. Further more, when I do use ur code, the code compiles instantly there is no waiting period

Comment: Do you have any code that uses `ts.URL`?

Comment: No unfortunately I do not

Comment: If you want to force a timeout using the test server created in the function, then you must make the request to the test server's URL, `ts.URL`.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in some of the comments, you need to make a request to the test server's endpoint (using `ts.URL`) as follows:

```
myRequest, err := http.NewRequest(http.MethodPost, ts.URL, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte("test")))
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
res, err := client.Do(myRequest)
if err != nil {
    t.Fatal(err)
}
[...]
```